# Returning positive values in R using only vectorization and indexes

Tags: r, indexing, vectorization

I have created a data frame which has string and integers. The integers which are positive and negative.
I have to change all the ints to be positive without using for/if loops but by only using vectorization and indexing. I have created one with a for loop but I am a bit stuck on the next part.

```
 df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5],
                 y = seq(-4,4,2),
                 z = c(3,4,-5,6,-8))
```

This is my loop to convert to positive.

```
    loop_df_fn <- function(data){
  for(i in names(data)){
    if(is.numeric(data[[i]])){
      data[[i]][data[[i]]<0] <- abs(data[[i]][data[[i]]< 0])*10
    }
  }
  return(data)
}
print((loop_df_fn(df)))
```

Comment: `df[-1] <- abs(df[-1])`

Comment: This would work perfectly if it was in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
df[] <- lapply(df , \(x) if(is.numeric(x)) abs(x)*10 else x)
```

- Output

```
  x y z
1 a 40 30
2 b 20 40
3 c 0  50
4 d 20 60
5 e 40 80
```

Comment: This still uses an if statement so it wouldn't satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I think all that is missing is *10 from this.

Answer (score 0):

A tidy solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~if_else(.<0, .*-10, .)))
```

Comment: This still uses an if statement so it wouldn't satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
rapply(df, \(x) (x*-10)^(x<0)*x^(x>0), 'numeric', how='replace')
  x  y  z
1 a 40  3
2 b 20  4
3 c  1 50
4 d  2  6
5 e  4 80

rapply(df, \(x) replace(x, x<0, x[x<0]*-10), 'numeric', how='replace')
  x  y  z
1 a 40  3
2 b 20  4
3 c  0 50
4 d  2  6
5 e  4 80
```

lastly:

```
ind <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
df[ind][df[ind]<0] <- df[ind][df[ind]<0] * -10
df
  x  y  z
1 a 40  3
2 b 20  4
3 c  0 50
4 d  2  6
5 e  4 80
```